# Issue with compare two fractions

Tags: java

I have two classes: Fraction and Test. I already do well with class Fraction, but class Test has some issues.

I want to allow the user enter the fractions and store in ArrayList, the user can compare two fraction from the array by choosing the index of the array. But when I compare two fraction, it doesn't work well!

class Fraction:

```
class Fraction {

    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;

    Fraction(int n, int d) {
        numerator = n;
        denominator = d;
    }

    public Fraction(int n) {
        this(n, 1);
    }

    public Fraction() {
        numerator = 0;
        denominator = 1;
    }

    public int getNumerator() {
        return numerator;
    }

    public void setNumerator(int numerator) {
        this.numerator = numerator;
    }

    public int getDenominator() {
        return denominator;
    }

    public void setDenominator(int denominator) {
        this.denominator = denominator;
    }

    public void display() {
        String s =  this.getNumerator() + "/" + this.getDenominator();
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    public double evaluate() {
        double n = numerator; 
        double d = denominator;
        return (n / d);
    }

    public boolean isEquals(Fraction f){
        int gcd1 = gcd(f.getNumerator(), f.getDenominator());
        double fractionFloatValue = (f.getNumerator()/gcd1) / (f.getDenominator()/gcd1); 
        int gcd2 = gcd(this.getNumerator(), this.getDenominator());
        double fractionFloatValue2 = (this.getNumerator()/gcd2) / (this.getDenominator()/gcd2);
        return (fractionFloatValue == fractionFloatValue2) ? true : false;

    }

    public Fraction add(Fraction f2) {
        Fraction r = new Fraction((numerator * f2.denominator)
                + (f2.numerator * denominator), (denominator * f2.denominator));
        return r;
    }

    static private int gcd(int x, int y) {
        return y == 0 ? x : gcd(y, x % y);
    }

    public static String asFraction(int x, int y) {
        int gcd = gcd(x, y);
        return (x / gcd) + "/" + (y / gcd);
    }

    /*public static void main(String[] argv) {

        Fraction f0 = new Fraction();
        Fraction f1 = new Fraction(3);
        Fraction f2 = new Fraction(20, 60);
        Fraction f3 = new Fraction(1, 3);

        System.out.println("--------------Testing constructors--------------");
        f0.display();
        f1.display();
        f2.display();
        System.out.println("--------------Test if two fractions is equal--------------");
        System.out.println(f2.isEquals(f1));
    }*/
}
```

and class Test:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void enterFraction(){
        ArrayList<Fraction> arr = new ArrayList<Fraction>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean check = false;
        int i = 1;
        while(!check){
            System.out.println("Enter fraction"+i+":");
            Fraction f = new Fraction();
            System.out.println("Enter Numerator: ");
            int numerator = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine();
            f.setNumerator(numerator);
            System.out.println("Enter Denominator: ");
            int denominator = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine();
            f.setDenominator(denominator);
            System.out.println("Your fraction"+i+" is: "+f.getNumerator()+"/"+f.getDenominator());
            arr.add(f);
            System.out.println("Want to compare fractions? (Y/Yes or N/No)");
            String compareRequest = scanner.nextLine();
            if(compareRequest.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
                System.out.println("Choose your target fraction!!! (enter the index of the array)");
                int position = scanner.nextInt();
                scanner.nextLine();
                Fraction targetFraction = arr.get(position);
                targetFraction.display();
                System.out.println("Choose your second fraction to compare!!! (enter the index of the array)");
                int position2 = scanner.nextInt();
                scanner.nextLine();
                Fraction secondFraction = arr.get(position2);
                secondFraction.display();
                boolean compareTwoFractions = secondFraction.isEquals(targetFraction);
                if(compareTwoFractions == true){
                    System.out.println("Two fractions are equal");
                }
                else if(compareTwoFractions == false){
                    System.out.println("Two fractions are not equal");
                }           
            }   
            i++;
            System.out.println("Do you want to enter more fraction? (Y/Yes or N/No)");
            String checkRequest = scanner.nextLine();
            if(checkRequest.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
                check = true;
            }
        }   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        enterFraction();
    }
}
```

I input like this:

```
Enter fraction1:
Enter Numerator: 
2
Enter Denominator: 
4
Your fraction1 is: 2/4
Want to compare fractions? (Y/Yes or N/No)
n
Do you want to enter more fraction? (Y/Yes or N/No)
y
Enter fraction2:
Enter Numerator: 
1
Enter Denominator: 
3
Your fraction2 is: 1/3
Want to compare fractions? (Y/Yes or N/No)
y
Choose your target fraction!!! (enter the index of the array)
0
2/4
Choose your second fraction to compare!!! (enter the index of the array)
1
1/3
Two fractions are equal
Do you want to enter more fraction? (Y/Yes or N/No)
```

You see it not work, `2/4 == 1/3`. Please point me somethings with this.

Comment: You see my class Fraction, I compare f2 and f1, it return false, but when I embed in class Test, it doesn't work like this.

Comment: Unrelated but, In your `isEquals` method, since all you are doing is testing the decimal value of the fraction, there is no need to calculate the gcd. Simply check `getNumerator() /getDenominator() ` it should return the same value. That is, if you don't use the identity concept in dasblinkenlights answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `getNumerator()`, `getDenominator()`, and `gcd` return an `int`. Therefore, the division inside your `equals` method is done in integers:

```
double fractionFloatValue = (f.getNumerator()/gcd1) / (f.getDenominator()/gcd1); 
...
double fractionFloatValue2 = (this.getNumerator()/gcd2) / (this.getDenominator()/gcd2);
```

The value of `fractionFloatValue` and `fractionFloatValue2` are, in fact, integers, even though they are assigned to variables of type `double`. Both `1/3` and `1/2` are proper fractions, so integer division evaluates to zero in both cases. That's why your `equals` returns `true` in both cases.

There are two ways to fix this:

- Declare `gcd1` and `gcd2` as `double`. This would force the division into `double`; unfortunately, your code would suffer from double comparison for equality, which is inherently imprecise, or
- Use identity `n1/d1 == n2/d2` when `n1*d2 == n2*d1`. This eliminates division, so you get perfect precision in your comparisons until you overflow (and you would not overflow with the constraints that you are using if you use `long` for the results of your multiplication).

Answer (score 1):

I change two line that @dasblinkenlight has mentioned by:

```
double fractionFloatValue = ((f.getNumerator()/gcd1)*1.0) / (f.getDenominator()/gcd1);

double fractionFloatValue2 = ((this.getNumerator()/gcd2)*1.0) / (this.getDenominator()/gcd2);
```

and It worked now.